# Creating alert box (jQuery, Bootstrap) but it keeps disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's start with a pen: https://codepen.io/Muzical84/pen/EbPXBP

```js
function validateInput(input, event) {
  'use strict';

  if (input == null || input !== "") {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: '/api/getAll'
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data !== null && $.isArray(data) && data.indexOf(input.toUpperCase()) === -1) { //The AJAX return is valid but the symbol does not exist.
          //debugger;
          $('#jsErrors').html('<p>The given symbol does not exist.</p>');

          $('#jsErrors').addClass('alert');
          $('#jsErrors').addClass('alert-danger');

          $('#jsErrors').removeClass('hidden');
          $('#jsErrors').removeClass('invisible');

          $('#jsErrors').show();
        } else {
          debugger;
          editWatchList(input.toUpperCase(), 'watch'); //Pass it along (function omitted from pen)
        }
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(errorThrown); //I am aware that this is less than ideal.  In the "real world", I would ask my supervisor how to handle this instance.
      })
      .always(function(a, textStatus, c) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
      });
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a symbol before submitting.');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is actually a partial, Laravel Blade, specifically. -->
<div id="jsErrors" class="hidden invisible" role="alert"></div>

<form id="add-symbol-form" class="form-inline" accept-charset=utf-8 autocomplete="off">
  <!-- Laravel CSRF field -->
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="symbol" id="symbol" placeholder="Enter a symbol..." required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" onClick="validateInput($('#symbol').val());">Add Symbol</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  //Enter will have the same effect as clicking the button
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if ($('#symbol').val() !== '' && e.which == 13) { //Only submit if the user hit enter AND there is something in the input box to validate.
        validateInput($('#symbol').val());
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is meant to be a rudimentary stock tracker, written in Laravel.  The HTML is a Blade partial in a wider page, and this snippet fires when the user wants to "watch" a new stock symbol.  The AJAX calls my Laravel API, works fine in Postman, huzzah!

However, if the user enters a symbol that isn't in the database, (I didn't decide this limitation, so please no comments about it =-\ ) I want to alert the user, hence the initially-empty-and-hidden `<div>` above the form.

If I use the debugger; statement to step through my code, the box shows, all of that works flawlessly, but then when my function ends, the `<div>` disappears entirely.

Why?  (And is it related to the irritating thing I've noticed where my address bar adds the query?  I want the address bar to say `project.dev` no matter what.)

PS: for what it's worth, I do have Vue available to me, via Laravel; I am not currently using it, but if it helps, it would literally be zero effort to include it.  I just know jack-all about Vue.

Comment: I don't see where your submit handler is cancelling the form submit.

Comment: @Taplar It's a click handler...

Comment: Of a submit button in a form, which unless you stop it will cause the form to submit to whatever endpoint the form points to.  The same page url if no endpoint is specified.  Which yours does not.

Comment: ...Fair...  So one option would be changing `type` to button, but I like knowing multiple ways to Do The Thing, so how, in JS, would I stop that?

Comment: Pass in the event to the handler and do `event.preventDefault()`.  Or put `return` before the method in your onclick, and make the method return false.

Comment: Alright, updated the code, and...the box is still disappearing.  (Edited both the pen and the inline code here.)

Comment: You're calling the prevent default inside one of the ajax (asynchronous) methods.  It has to be called in the normal flow of the logic.  At the start of the method is usually where it's placed if you **always** want to prevent the event default.  Though you might try changing the element to a normal button and not a submit button, to see if this is your issue in the first place.

Comment: Oh! That does make a difference o.o  I thought that, since the closure automatically has access to `event`, I would do it the way I did.  Works now! Thanks, @Taplar ! ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from question comments ...

It appears that you are processing a click event off of a submit button in a form.  This will result in the form submitting and potentially reloading the page, without regard that you are performing ajax logic.

In order to prevent this, you'll most likely want to either change the submit button to be a regular button so that the form is not submitted when it is clicked; or pass the event into the onclick handler and call `event.preventDefault()` outside of your ajax logic so the form will not be submitted.